# Unity Embedded Browser Asset from Zen Fulcrum - Cant find the HTML File

Tags: unity-game-engine, browser, embedded-browser

How can I obtain the HTML content of a page loaded in the Embedded Browser asset for Unity?

I have been trying to get the HTML content of a loaded page for the past three days without success.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with some guidance on how to obtain the HTML content of a page loaded in the Embedded Browser asset. Is there a specific function or method that I should be using? Or is there some other way to access the HTML content?

Thank you in advance for any help or advice that can be provided.

I have been trying to get the HTML content of a loaded page.

Is there a specific function or method that I should be using? Or is there some other way to access the HTML content?

Comment: From what I can read on the [Embedded Browser documentation](https://zenfulcrum.com/browser/docs/Readme.html), you can call native JS functions from the `Browser` in your scene. I'd guess that you can call `document.querySelector` as well to access an element inside the DOM like this: `browser.CallFunction("document.querySelector(#id-you-want-to-access).Then(ret => { do something with the result });".

Comment: i will try it thank you, if it works i will reply again

Comment: i tryed it in the following way but it never jumps in to the function, here is the code :
        browser.CallFunction($"document.querySelector('#{id}').outerHTML").Then(ret => 
        {
            var sasdasd = ret;
            if(ret.Value != null) 
            {
                htmlContent = (string)ret.Value;
            }
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a Solution guys just like this:

browser.EvalJS("document.documentElement.outerHTML").Then(res => Debug.Log("Document contents: " + res)).Done();